# Prolog iteration off by 1

Tags: list, prolog, iteration

I have an iterator called `myfor` such that when I call `myfor(3,7,X).` I want it to return `X = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. However, this code only returns `X = [4, 5, 6, 7]`. It skips out on the first. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
myfor(A, A, []) :- !.

myfor(Start,End, Z) :-

    End > Start,
    NewValue is Start+1,
    myfor(NewValue,End, L),
    append([NewValue], L, Z).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to implement a for/next loop in prolog is a strong indication that you are thinking in terms of *imperative* programming, where you tell the computer what to do, rather than in terms of *declarative* programming, where you describe the solution and let Prolog's inference engine figure it out.

If, however, you want to generate a list containing an ordered range of numbers, something like the following will "git'er done" with the magic of a difference list:

```
range( X , X , [X] )
  .
range( X , Y , [X|Z] ) :-
  X < Y ,
  X1 is X + 1 ,
  range( X1 , Y , Z )
  .
range( X , Y , [X|Z] ) :-
  X > Y ,
  X1 is X - 1 ,
  range( X1 , Y , Z )
  .
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't been able to check this in Prolog (as I don't have it on my work machine). Here's my 2 bits

```
myfor(A, A, [A]) :- !.

myfor(Start,End, Z) :-
End > Start,
NewValue is Start+1,
myfor(NewValue,End, L),
append([Start], L, Z).
```

Comment: You can make it tail recursive by dropping the last line in the second clause and changing the head to `myfor(Start,End,[Start|L]) :-`. Gets rid of the append call.

Answer (score 1):

btw if you use swi-prolog and certainly some other prologs, `between/3` is close to what you call `myfor/3` and with one or two `listing/1` calls you could get a good idea of how it's implemented. a findall on a between should do what your predicate does.